# Convert string to int and get sum of numbers

Tags: java, string, char, int

When I test this code it always returns 0 and I'm not sure why.

```
public class test {
    public int sumOfDigits(String s) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            char cur = s.charAt(i);

            if (cur >= 0 && cur <= 9) {
                sum += cur - '0';
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `if (cur >= 0 && cur <= 9)` to `if (cur >= '0' && cur <= '9')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it, but your problem is that you need to subtract `'0'` from all places where you use `cur` as a number. The easiest way to fix this is just to subtract `'0'` when you first assign `cur`:

```
public class test {

    public int sumOfDigits(String s){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            char cur = (char)(s.charAt(i) - '0'); //Java autocasts to int when you subtract

            if (cur >= 0 && cur <= 9){
                sum += cur;
            }
        }


        return sum;

    }

}
```

You could also just add `- '0'` everywhere you use `cur` if you don't want to corrupt the actual character value of `cur`:

```
if ((cur - '0') >= 0 && (cur - '0') <= 9){
    sum += (cur - '0');
}
```

Comment: yes, when i'm typing my answer , your answer didn't with casting. after posting my answer i saw it. that means you have edited it while i'm typing the answer. anyway i will remove my answer because you are the first person who put the answer
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach: I break the string and store it in an array parts. And then convert each piece of string to integer and then add them to sum. Please ask me if any of it doesn't make sense. Thanks

```
public int sumOfDigits(String s){
String[] parts = s.split("");
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < parts.length; i++){
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);           
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much simply:

```
public int sumOfDigits(String s) {
    int sum = -1;
    try {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
        sum = 0;
        while(n!=0) {
            sum = sum + n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
        }
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println(nfe);
        System.out.println("Given string is not a number!");
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Since the sum of digits can never be negative, it returns -1 when the input is non-number string.

Comment: This doesn't work if there are any non-digit characters in the string

Comment: @River String having non-digit characters is not a number in the first place, and regarding that as a number is another mistake. The OP mentions in the title *Convert string to int*. And yes it 'doesn't work', but only it 'doesn't work wrongly'. Anyway, I have edited to make it work `:-)`

Comment: I had assumed that the "get sum of numbers" in the title of the question implied that the input string contained characters that were *not* numbers. (This is also implied by OP's code not failing with non-number input.) However you make a good point that "convert string to int" does suggest the opposite. (And I could be attributing an "implication" to what is just lazy coding.) In any case, I'll remove my downvote and let my comment warn those who want to be able to handle non-digit characters away from this answer.